# Does Human Form's bonus count for every power it applies to or just once?

Tags: fate, dresden-files

I'm alittle confused about the ruling for how human form would work in regards to multiple powers. If someone wants to have Inhuman Toughness, Speed, and Strength, does Human Form give them a point back for each one they can't use while human, or just once? I see problems with both of these

If it returns points every time, you can gain a huge number of points back by just having all your powers not work while a human. This seems abusable and not intended for design

However, if the point reward only counts once, then it seems unfair to make it apply to other powers. For instance, it would make more sense to just say you can't use inhuman toughness while a human, but the rest of the powers are on all the time. This might not be the idea behind the character though, and feels really counter-intuitive as a design. I can't find any good examples in the book either.

Comment: This is one of many reasons I prefer Dresden Files Accelerated.

Comment: A single rebate point isn't quite as unfair as it may appear at first glance.  If you think through the Dresden files books, the Alphas were rarely -- if ever -- hindered by the inability to go wolf, it was just a minor issue that needed a degree of management.  Supernatural conflicts already happen 'in the shadows', this ability just puts a small delay on you for *one* round when doing were stuff.  From my personal play experience, it just doesn't come up much as an issue.

Comment: @Paul what for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by examples in 'Our World' reward only counts once. (See Loup-Garou, Alphas and Hexenwolfes).

And it is "unfair" to apply to other powers from point of 'effective' point spending. However it is story, setting and kit appropriate to use it that way.

In current books and setting all "Human Form" users are were-people. If you check existing templates "Human Form" is a must for all were types (Were-Form and Lycanthrope). It is not used in any other types of character or templates. If you creating something that is not really where template (take it in mind that Jekyll/Hyde and Banner/Hulk are also classical were people templates) and something that is only mimic human but actually superhuman you should consider using "Human Guise".

Comment: Is there any significant bonus to using human form over guise?

Comment: Human Guise do not limit usage of any abilities. But is is not ideal disguise as even mere mortals can see through it (see Tigress ghoul-mercenary).